# Taxicab metric and Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Consider (ℝ,Ƭ) with the topology induced by the taxicab metric.  Using the definition for Hausdorff, give an example of why (ℝ,Ƭ) is Hausdorff.

The finite complement topology on ℝ is not Hausdorff.  Explain why ℝ with the finite complement topology is non-metrizable.

I have no clue where to go with either of these questions. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ask one question per question please. Also, explain your notation. In your first question, I can only guess what you mean by $(ℝ,Ƭ)$; I don't know what you mean by the taxicab metric on $(ℝ,Ƭ)$; and so on.

Comment: taxicab metric on $\mathbb{R}$ is simply the ${usual}$ metric on $\mathbb{R}$ induced by absolute value...so if you know the definition of Hausdorff then this is an easy exercise (which I think you should do on your own if you are reading about space being metrisable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, you should review the proof that *any* metric space is Hausdorff.

As for the second question: you can prove that $\mathbb R$ with the cofinite topology is not Hausdorff using the identity
$$
U\cap V=(U^c\cup V^c)^c.
$$
This leads to the conclusion that this space is not metrizable, since again, every metric space is Hausdorff.

Answer (score 0):

Note that any two distinct elements $x,y$ in metric space can be separated by open balls centered at these points of radius $r/3$ where $d(x,y)=r\neq 0.$

Comment: what does taxicab metric on $\mathbb{R}$ means ?

Comment: @seker Thanks for pointing out the error. It is usual metric.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is a metric space , then it is an Hausdorff space!
In particoular any space that isn't an Hausdorff space isn't metrizable, i.e. $\mathbb{R}$ with finite complement topology isn't metrizable.